# (mips) Cacheflush function on arm/arm64

Tags: android, arm, mips, arm64

as part of a project, I try to compile a .c file for Android10 (a Pixel 3) for arm64 using the [ninja buildsystem](https://ninja-build.org/). This .c file is part of a PoC that was already successfully used (so, it should work somehow).

The problem is now: this file contains a reference to the "cacheflush" function, that is well defined for [bionic/MIPS](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/37953ee3feb60b84e43349df0b13544367ca1cd7/libc/arch-mips/bionic/cacheflush.c#79), but not for [arm64](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/tegra/+/android-tegra-3.10/arch/arm64/include/asm/cacheflush.h). The error message is: `error: use of undeclared identifier 'cacheflush'`

As I said, the example is referenced to work. I already installed the android ndk/sdk and other dependencies that were listed in the project. I also tested including different header files (such as cacheflush.h and unistd.h)

Can anybody help me to get this function to work? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am using "cacheflush" for poc as well, if you type "man cacheflush" in linux-based distrubutions, you can see notes like this in synopsis:

> Note: On some architectures, there is no glibc wrapper for this system call; see NOTES.

So i guess no cacheflush function in ARM architecture.

You can search ARM instruction set reference for instructions which do the same job(like clflush in x86).